# Allman-style braces in TypeScript

Tags: indentation, curly-braces, typescript

Could the TypeScript compiler be adapted to allow safe use of Allman-style braces in [places where it classically breaks JavaScript code](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/)? TypeScript is designed to generate idiomatic JavaScript, so the resulting braces would be generated in K&R style anyhow.

As an example:

```
// currently breaks in JS (and won't compile in TypeScript)
function getPerson() {        
    // compiler inserts semicolon after return, return executes prematurely
    return 
    {
        firstname: "Eric",
        lastname: "Allman"
    };
}
```

P.S. I'm just curious; not really interested in debating whether or not it's a "good idea" to go against generally-accepted JS practices.

Comment: I realize you don't want to debate, but why handicap TS developers with a style that is incompatible with the web? (JS) If you got used to that and had to write some JS (inevitably), you'd have to switch. TS K&R style is also consistent with Dart (and Google Go). Why not have everyone live in harmony?

Comment: I definitely understand that - and it's probably the right choice to keep 1:1 wherever possible. I'm just used to another language that is less restrictive (either style is fine), and in that language, I find navigating code easier with Allman-style braces. But, with decent tooling the difference in the experience goes way down anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

What the TypeScript compiler does do is add the semi-colon, so you can see the problem - rather than waiting for the browser to implicitly add it and cause odd behaviour.

Whether this is something the community wants to add isn't something that can be answered on Stack Overflow - you would have to [start a discussion on Codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions).

Comment: Excellent - now we wait and see :)